# How to compile Google Closure code in modules using closure_builder.py?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

How can I compile Google Closure code in multiple modules using [closure_builder.py](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder)?

I tried this command:

```
python closurebuilder.py 
--root closure/closure-library 
--root closure/client 
--namespace="client.start" 
--output_mode=compiled 
--compiler_jar=compiler.jar 
--output_file closure/compiled.js 
--compiler_flags=--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS 
--compiler_flags=--module base:1  
--compiler_flags=--js=closure/modules/base.js  
--compiler_flags=--module editor:1  
--compiler_flags=--js=closure/modules/editor.js  
--compiler_flags=--module maps:1  
--compiler_flags=--js=closure/modules/maps.js  
--compiler_flags=--module uploader:1  
--compiler_flags=--js=closure/modules/uploader.js  
--compiler_flags=--module visualization:1  
--compiler_flags=--js=closure/modules/visualization.js 
--compiler_flags=--output_wrapper="(function() {%output%})();"
```

But the following error is thrown:

```
closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "closurebuilder.py", line 256, in <module>
    main()
  File "closurebuilder.py", line 196, in main
    sources.add(_PathSource(js_path))
  File "closurebuilder.py", line 167, in __init__
    super(_PathSource, self).__init__(source.GetFileContents(path))
  File "source.py", line 110, in GetFileContents
    fileobj = open(path)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'base:1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ran into a similar issue, except that it wasn't 'base:1' but 'Files'. Turns out, i was executing the script from C:\Program Files (x86)... and those extra spaces messed with the Closure script and how it resolves JS files.
Executing it from a path with no space solved it, hope you can fix it as well, maybe try adding quotes over arguments

Fabien

Comment: Do you compile your code into multiple modules or one single file? I'm able to compile to one file, but not into multiple modules.